# How can I stop jQuery from hiding my Image and Game version?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a similar website to this. I'm using `jQuery` for my searchbar. It works fine, but the problem is that I want it to only hide the `<div class="gameDiv">` not all the children in it, so I can still see the Picture and version of the game and not only the game name.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() { 
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); 
        $("#root *").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.gameDiv {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 0.25fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 8rem;
    img {
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 3;
        margin-left: 8px;
    }
    p {
        grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-column-end: 3;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="root">
            
        <div class="gameDiv"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZhAM.png" class="gameIcon" alt="test"><a href="test">My Game</a><p>10.2</p></div>
        <div class="gameDiv"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZhAM.png" class="gameIcon" alt="test"><a href="test">My second Game</a><p>10.3</p></div></div>
```

Comment: So instead of selecting all the elements, select the gameDiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() { 
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); 
        $(".gameDiv").filter(function(index,item) {
            $(this).toggle($(this).children('a').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.gameDiv {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 0.25fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 8rem;
    img {
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 3;
        margin-left: 8px;
    }
    p {
        grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-column-end: 3;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="root">
            
        <div class="gameDiv"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZhAM.png" class="gameIcon" alt="test"><a href="test">My Game</a><p>10.2</p></div>
        <div class="gameDiv"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZhAM.png" class="gameIcon" alt="test"><a href="test">My second Game</a><p>10.3</p></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you select all elements inside the root

```
$("#root *")
```

Change it so you only select the div

```
$("#root .gameDiv")
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() { 
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); 
        $("#root .gameDiv")
          .hide()
          .filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
          })
          .show();
    });
});
```

```css
.gameDiv {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 0.25fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 8rem;
    img {
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 3;
        margin-left: 8px;
    }
    p {
        grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-column-end: 3;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="root">
            
        <div class="gameDiv"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZhAM.png" class="gameIcon" alt="test"><a href="test">My Game</a><p>10.2</p></div>
        <div class="gameDiv"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZhAM.png" class="gameIcon" alt="test"><a href="test">My second Game</a><p>10.3</p></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Change the element you filter on from "#root *" to ".gameDiv".

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() { 
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); 
        $(".gameDiv").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.gameDiv {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 0.25fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 8rem;
    img {
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 3;
        margin-left: 8px;
    }
    p {
        grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-column-end: 3;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="root">
            
        <div class="gameDiv"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZhAM.png" class="gameIcon" alt="test"><a href="test">My Game</a><p>10.2</p></div>
        <div class="gameDiv"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZhAM.png" class="gameIcon" alt="test"><a href="test">My second Game</a><p>10.3</p></div></div>
```